# A fast algorithm instead of permutation

Tags: c++, algorithm, linear-algebra, graph-algorithm

I need to find a fast algorithm for a problem with following inputs and outputs.

Input:

n pair of integer numbers as operands and three operator(+,-,*)

Output:

If somebody could put the operators between all operands and the results be n different numbers, the program will say:"It's possible.". Otherwise it will say:"It's impossible.". On the other hand repetition of operators is allowed but for the results is not allowed. A usual method is to use of the permutation; but it is very time consuming.

An example:

```
Input:
3  5 
2  1
6  3
Output:
Possible
```

For this example one possibility is '-' operator for the first pair of operands and '+' operator for rest of them.

May some body help me with a fast algorithm for this problem(also I have to use c++)?

Comment: Show us some code what you have tried so far.

Comment: You *have* [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? And you know how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? If not then please follow the links and read the articles.

Comment: I have not tried any code because I'm going to design its algorithm at first.

Comment: @alikefayati Stack Overflow is a Q & A site about code. If the main focus is on algorithm design, you may have better luck in http://programmers.stackexchange.com or other Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: If you go to programmers.se, read their rules before posting!

Comment: The algorithm must be fast. It's category is not important. In fact I need a fast method because using of the permutation is very slow.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know any thing about dynamic programming.

Comment: Does any body know how I could change this problem to a maximum flow problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn this into a maximum flow problem.

Let us denote by `N` the number of pairs (equations).

First, notice that for each pair we have at most three possible results (since we have three operators).

Consider the set of all possible results from all the equations, let us denote this set of numbers as `A`

Construct a graph `G`, which will have two special nodes `s` (the source), `t` (the sink), one node corresponding to each element of `A`, and finally, one node for each of the `N` input pairs of numbers.

The edges of `G` will be created as follows:

- an edge from `s` to each node corresponding to `A`.
- an edge from each node corresponding to `A` to each node corresponding to a pair of numbers that can produce the respective result from `A` (remember that each input pair may produce 3 different values).
- an edge from each node corresponding to an equation to the sink `t`.

Assign to each of these edges a capacity equal to 1.

Now, run a maximum flow algorithm. If the value of the flow is equal to `N`, then we can produce `N` different results.

Indeed, in order to have a flow of `N` arriving to the sink, we must have a flow of one from each of the `N` equations in the layer before. We can also recover the solution by looking from which number in `A` each equation obtains its unit input flow.

---

EDIT:

See below a visualization for the above algorithm, for the following input pairs:

```
3 1
2 2
2 1
```

[image: Sample]

The set `A` is `{2, 4, 3, 0, 1}`. Some numbers can be obtained from multiple pairs, *e.g.* `2 = 3 - 1 = 2 * 1`. The effect of this is that the node corresponding to number `2` is connected to both the node with `3 1` and also to the one with `2 1`.

All the edges have unit capacity (as described above).

After running the max flow algorithm from `s` to `t`, the result is `3` and one possible way to deliver this flow is illustrated by the bold edges. The solution produced in this case is `2 = 3 - 1`, `4 = 2 * 2`, `1 = 2 - 1`;

Comment: Thank you. In fact the best algorithm for this problem is maximum flow. But my problem is to change the problem to a maximum flow one. Because I'm not familiar with it. Your explanation is very helpful. But may you show it with an example?

Comment: I'm happy it's helpful, I will draw an example a little bit later today.

Comment: @alikefayati done, thanks for the accept, please let me know if anything is still unclear.

Comment: thanks a lot. I will write the program and give you the feedback of result.